# How can I transfer the text from a username to another form? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I am pretty new to VB.NET and programming in general so bear with me.

I am working on a sort of "blog" application and my first form is a login form, I would like to take the username from the login form and take that text and put it into the blog form.

Here's what I have on the blog form:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim X As Boolean


    If txtBlog.Text = String.Empty Then
        X = False
    Else
        X = True

    End If

    If X = True Then
        lblMessage1.Text = txtBlog.Text
        txtBlog.Hide()
        btnSubmit.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
```

Here's what I have for the login form:

```
Public Class login
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If txtUser.Text = "admin" And txtPassw.Text = "password" Then
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login")
        txtPassw.Text = ""
        txtUser.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new instance of the class `login()` which allows you to access variables of that Instance

Try this:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim X As Boolean
    Dim userName As String

dim Z as new login()
userName=Z.txtUser.Text 


    If txtBlog.Text = String.Empty Then
        X = False
    Else
        X = True

    End If

    If X = True Then
        lblMessage1.Text = txtBlog.Text
        txtBlog.Hide()
        btnSubmit.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
```